# R -> creating data set with repetitive values

Tags: r, dataset

I got the to solve the following problem:

> create a dataset holding the Turnover (runif 500;1000) integer values for your 4 Sales representatives for the last 4 years each salesperson selling 4 different products (Mars, Snickers, Bounty, Milkeyway);  additioanlly add a column with the integer CostofSales (runif 50;150) finally calculate the Earnings in an own column. Combine all values into a dataframe

so I did:

```
Years <- rep(c(2021:2018),16)
Years

Sales <- rep(c("Chris","Lucas","Cara","Bia"),16)
View(Sales)                                                                                             

Product <- rep(c("Mars","Snickers","Bounty","Milkway"),16)
Product

Turnover <- c(runif(64,500,1000))
Turnover

df <- data.frame(Years,Sales,Product,Turnover)
View(df)
```

But the 'dataframe' is messed up:

[image]

Can anyone help me? THANK YOU

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? What do you mean by "messed up"? What you expect to see differently than what you have?

Comment: Hey Gregor! 
Thank you for your question!
What I aimed was, something like:
2020 Cara Milkway + turnover
2020 Cara Mars + turnover
2020 Cara Bounty + turnover
2020 Cara Snickers + turnover
2020 Lucas Milkway + turnover
...
2018 Cara Milkway + turnover
2018 Cara Mars + turnover
2018 Cara Bounty + turnover
2018 Cara Snickers + turnover
2018 Lucas Milkway + turnover
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying for

```
Years <- rep(c(2021:2018), each=16)
Sales <- rep(rep(c("Chris","Lucas","Cara","Bia"), each=4),  4)
Product <- rep(c("Mars",  "Snickers", "Bounty", "Milkway"), 16)
Turnover <- runif(64, 500, 1000)

df <- data.frame(Years,Sales,Product,Turnover)
df[c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36), ]
#    Years Sales Product Turnover
# 4   2021 Chris Milkway 964.8695
# 8   2021 Lucas Milkway 799.1933
# 12  2021  Cara Milkway 613.6976
# 16  2021   Bia Milkway 970.3118
# 20  2020 Chris Milkway 598.2047
# 24  2020 Lucas Milkway 951.0657
# 28  2020  Cara Milkway 537.1925
# 32  2020   Bia Milkway 720.0880
# 36  2019 Chris Milkway 759.2236
```

Comment: HEY!! YES!! Exactly what I needed! 

although I dont understand the line:
> df[c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36), ]

What exactly did you do here? Because from what I see we had pretty much the same lines right?

Could you also maybe elucidate the difference between sales and Product? is it the same way to do but written diferently?

THANK YOU once again!

Comment: The `df[..., ]` was just to print the same lines you printed in your picture. There are multiple ways to get what you want, but for each year, you want each Sales person, for each Product. We repeat each Sales person four times (one for each product) and then repeat that block 4 times for each year. For the Product we repeat each block of 4 Products 16 times.

Comment: i see! 
Thank you =)